# I have my model structure like this: ROOT/models/*.py files for each model

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

But I have a problem importing models in each other.
EX:

model1 imports: model2, model3, model4

model2 imports: model1, model3, model4

model3 imports: model1, model2, model4

model4 imports: model1, model2, model3

But this gives me errors, saying it can't import :S

Error like this:

```
File "C:\GAE\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1790, in LoadModuleRestricted
description)
File "D:\Totty\webDevelopment\TottysWorld\src\models\WO_list_WO.py", line 3, in <module>
class WOListWO(db.Model):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you create `__init__.py` in models directory?